# Showing error while routing from one screen to another in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, navigation

I'm moving from one screen to another screen but it shows error in routing.
My First screen named as `VenueOption` and the second one is `PlayerOption`

This is Venue Option Class

```
class VenueOption extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userType;

  const VenueOption({Key key, @required this.userType}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ProfileBoard(
        userType: userType,
      ),
    );
    /*return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home:Scaffold(
      body: ProfileBoard(
        userType: userType,
      ),)
    );*/
  }
}
```

There is a button inside `ProfileBoard`, this class is statefull class and navigation screen to 'PlayerOption' by this method

```
 void pushToDashboard(BuildContext context) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlayerOption()),
      );
      // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VenuProfile(userType: userType,)),);
    }
```

`PlayerOption` class

```
class PlayerOption extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlayerOptionState createState() => _PlayerOptionState();
}

class _PlayerOptionState extends State<PlayerOption> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return Scaffold(
   resizeToAvoidBottomInset:false,
   body: PlayerOptionHome(),
 );
   /* return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home:Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset:false,

        body: PlayerOptionHome(),

      )
    );*/
  }
}
```

> ```
> > The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
> > _OverlayEntry-[LabeledGlobalKey<_OverlayEntryState>#be2a0](dirty, state: _OverlayEntryState#6e209): The getter 'status' was called on
> > null. Receiver: null Tried calling: status When the exception was
> > thrown, this was the stack:
> > #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
> > #1      ModalRoute._buildModalBarrier (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:1239:27)
> > #2      _OverlayEntryState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:170:25)
> > #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3825:27)
> > #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3739:15)
> > #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
> > #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3722:5)
> > #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3864:11)
> ```
>
> Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'status'
>   was called on null.

I made `PlayerOption` with `MaterialApp` now the screen is navigating  from 'VenueOption`to`PlayerOption`but when I tried to call another screen from`PlayerOption`to`PlayerConnect ` showing error

> ```
> > Another exception was thrown:
> > 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line
> > 1562 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
> ```

```
class PlayerConnect extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FeedView(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try updating the flutter version, it may work

Comment: @ManojPerumarath will it solve my problem? recently I'm facing this issue, before this, it was working fine.

Comment: I'm Trying to update SDK.

Comment: @ManojPerumarath still facing the same error

Comment: @ManojPerumarath 1.7.8+hotfix 3

Comment: @ManojPerumarath I have searched the keyword in whole project nothing like that I have found

Comment: @ManojPerumarath please see my updated question, The last portion I have added

Comment: @ManojPerumarath see my updated code

Comment: Did you try by changing `MaterialApp` as the base for all screen instead of adding it everywhere

Comment: @ManojPerumarath i have tried adding `MaterialApp' but the last screen is not navigating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```dart
class VenueOption extends StatelessWidget {
  final String userType;
  BuildContext ctx;

  const VenueOption({Key key, @required this.userType}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ctx = context;
    return Scaffold(
      body: ProfileBoard(
        userType: userType,
      ),
    ); 
  }
 void pushToDashboard() {

    Navigator.of(ctx).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => PlayerOption()));
 }
}
```